# Regex to check if string is not empty and does not only contain html tags

Tags: regex

I need a regex (only one allowed) to check if a string is not empty and does not only contain html tags.

For example the input could be

- (empty string)
- <span></span>
- <span>Test</span>
- <span></span>Test

The regex should only match for

- <span>Test</span>
- <span></span>Test

I found no workig expressions for all cases

- ^((?!><).)+$
- ^((?!<+>).)+$
- ^((?!<*+>/).)+$

There must a be a solution :)

Comment: Try this: `^.*>[^<].*$`

Comment: Possibly through: `(?:^<(\w+)>)(?:\w+<\/\1>$|<\/\1>\w+$)`?

Comment: Thanks you both, I checked it with my samples and it worked. I have not listet the regular case "some text" which should also match. I tried to modify your expressions to get it working but failed again :(

Comment: Maybe just `|^\w+$` after my first suggestion?

Comment: Thanks, JvdV, but this allows empty strings and "<span></span>".

Comment: You [sure](https://regex101.com/r/ZliNc0/6)?

Comment: You can try `^(?:.*>[^<].*|[^>]+)$` but your requirement is tricky. Is `Te>st` a valid string for you?

Comment: @JvdV my mistake, sorry, it works for that cases.

Comment: @EganWolf thanks, that should match all cases. `Te>st` would be ok, because it is no html tag

Comment: You may replace `<\/?\w+(?:\s+[^>=]+=\"[^\"]*\")*\s*>` by nothing, filtering any properly formed tag. If remaining string not empty, then not empty? It won't check if tag is legit or if tagging is balanced though, a parser would be a better solution if such conditions are needed.